# How do I manage registration as a preference in pushwoosh?

Tags: android, push-notification, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I followed the [official guide](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-gcm-push-notifications-guide/) but found that it just registers your app for notifications over and over, and there's no way a user can opt out. There doesn't seem to be a way to tell if the device is registered or not because the `getRemoteNotificationStatus` method is not available in the Android version of the plugin. How can I get this information?

I thought I'd save it as a preference in the app so I wouldn't have to query anything external, but more recent versions of Android allow you to disable notifications outside of the app. Will this deregister/conflict with my separate in-app preference?

My code (that I'm testing with) so far:

```
(function() {
    var pushPrefApply = function() {
        app.pushPref(function(pushPref) {
            console.log('pushPref', pushPref);
            if (!pushPref) {
                window.plugins.pushNotification.unregisterDevice(
                    function() {
                        console.log('unreg ok', arguments);
                    },
                    function() {
                        console.log('unreg fail', arguments);
                    }
                );
                return;
            }
            window.plugins.pushNotification.registerDevice(
                {
                    projectid: '123456789012',
                    appid : 'F0000-BAAAA'
                },
                function(pushToken) {
                    console.log('reg ok', arguments);
                },
                function(status) {
                    console.log('reg fail', arguments);
                }
            );
        });
    };

    //UI code for changing push preference goes here, calls pushPrefApply

    $document.on('appready', function() {
        pushPrefApply();
    });
})();
```

`$document` is not a typo, it's defined already. `app.pushPref` is the preference fetching function. `window.plugins.pushNotification.onDeviceReady` has been done elsewhere on `deviceready`. `appready` is a synthesized event that I fire after both `deviceready` and another event triggered by a local data storage library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the right thing.

Unfortunately that's the only option as Android does not provide you with the API to get push notifications enabled/disabled status. And this settings is buried so deep in the options I really doubt users will be able to find it.

Anyway keeping the registration information locally is the only option at the moment.